Why tbl_summary add a space to numbers with more than 4 digits?
How can I make tbl_summary not to add a space in my numbers when they are 4 digits long?
For example, in this image you can see that 1888 and 1055 are presented like 1 888 and 1 055.

This is my code:
base %>%
    select(triajedic,
           residencia_dico,
           Posee_OS) %>%
    mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
    tbl_summary(by= triajedic,
                missing = "always",
                statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n}"),
                missing_text= "Casos perdidos",
                digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0,1))) %>%
    add_overall

I am expecting that the numbers that have more than 4 digits doesnt have a space

Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, that is, data and code we can run on our machines that replicates your issue. Use reprex.tidyverse.com as a guide to create your example.

The space is in place of the decimal mark (e.g., the comma or period, typically).

The end result is a gt table, so you probably can use fmt_numeric and fmt_integer from the gt package to format the desired columns, particularly by using sep_mark="". Without an MWE I can't give a proper answer.
